# iOS Contacts Favorites

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-privateapi

I am trying to access the favorite contacts via the private frameworks. I followed the [siphon code](http://code.google.com/p/siphon/) and got the frameworks from [iOS-Runtime-Headers](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers)

The code that I wrote to access the list is:

```
    NSBundle *b = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework"];
  BOOL success = [b load];

  Class favs = NSClassFromString(@"ABFavoritesList");

  id favList = [favs sharedInstance];

  NSLog(@"Favs count = %d", [[favList entries] count]);
```

For some reason the the entries are being fetched as nil. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code and `success` is equals to `NO`, and `favs` and `favList` are equals to `nil`, I guess the `AddressBookUI.framework` fail to load.

After that, I tried adding (linking) my project with the `AddressBook.framework` and `AddressBookUI.framework` frameworks, and executing this code (note that the bundle load part is removed):

```
Class favs = NSClassFromString(@"ABFavoritesList");
id favList = [favs sharedInstance];
NSLog(@"Favs count = %d", [[favList entries] count]);
```

and it works. Maybe you can try that.

By the way, you probably know it, but it is never a good idea to directly use private code (in this case `ABFavoritesList`), as this code may change in the future.